# jQuery dataTables - left align sort icon

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

as you can see the sort icons on my Datatable are on the far right of the column:

[image]

Is it possible to align these on the left so they appear just after the text?

ie.

```
# ^            Technician ^              Completed Date ^
```

Thank you

Code as requested:

```
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table-d">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans %} id {% endtrans %}</th>
                <th>{% trans %} technician {% endtrans %}</th>
                <th>{% trans %} date {% endtrans %}</th>
                <th>{% trans %} summary {% endtrans %}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And:

```
$('#table-d').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ path('table_data') }}",
    "pageLength": 10
})'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, that is not possible to appear right after the text, since the arrows in fact are background images in CSS classes attached dynamically to the `<th>`'s. But you can change the position from far right to left :

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_asc.png") no-repeat center left;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_desc.png") no-repeat center left;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_both.png") no-repeat center left;
}
```

[image]

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ttcz5odt/**

---

**Update - how to place arrow icons directly after text.**

Gave it some extra thoughts - with a little "hack" it is indeed possible. The trick is to disable the `<th>` backgrounds and continuously inject / remove `<span>`'s with the original dataTables backgrounds instead.

CSS (besides disabling the original) :

```css
span.arrow-hack {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
span.asc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_asc.png") no-repeat center right;
}
span.desc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_desc.png") no-repeat center right;
}
span.sort {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_both.png") no-repeat center right;
}
```

script :

```js
var spanSorting = '<span class="arrow-hack sort">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>',
    spanAsc = '<span class="arrow-hack asc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>',
    spanDesc = '<span class="arrow-hack desc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';

$("#example").on('click', 'th', function() {
    $("#example thead th").each(function(i, th) {
        $(th).find('.arrow-hack').remove();
        var html = $(th).html(),
            cls = $(th).attr('class');
        switch (cls) {
            case 'sorting_asc' : 
                $(th).html(html+spanAsc); break;
            case 'sorting_desc' : 
                $(th).html(html+spanDesc); break;
            default : 
                $(th).html(html+spanSorting); break;
        }
    });     
});
```

update the arrow icons :

```js
$("#example th").first().click().click();
```

Now it looks like what we wanted! : 
[image]

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dmn4q141/**

Comment: Upvoted just for answering after all this time! Shame to know it's not possible though; but I came to accept it a few months ago.

Comment: Great!

For those who are using the "Table Sorter" plugin in WordPress, you have to override this block of style: `table.tablesorter thead tr th`.

Add to it: `background-position: left center !important;`

Answer (score 28):

I have managed to do this by applying the following styles (better if applied as last css include file definition)

```
/**
 * Datatables Sorting icons on left
 */

table.dataTable thead > tr > th {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: initial !important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
    left: 8px !important;
    right: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Working on Bootsrap styling as well.

Comment: perfect, thanks ! :))
i just added this line to :
- add some padding on the left (so the text doesn't overlaps the icon)
- remove the padding on the right (which tends to make the small columns larger)

`table.dataTable thead td.sorting, table.dataTable thead td.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead td.sorting_desc { padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 0px !important; }`

Comment: had to add also the :before, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**You can change css as:**

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{
    background-position: left center;
}
```

following is css for make arrow and heading more attractive.(not required)

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{
    background-position: 5px center;
}
table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    padding: 10px 18px 10px 28px;           
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, maybe because I use bootsrap styling.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice solution posted on [the DataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25819).

Comment: Solution points to a broken link.

Comment: Solution points to https://live.datatables.net/laxohaca/2195/edit (I changed the jquery script reference from http to https for the code to work)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sort and simple answer.

> for my screen 160px left is enough.

Adjust it as per your need.

```
 #table-d thead .sorting::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc::after 
 {
        left: 160px;
        right: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to move the background image:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    background-position: 0px !important;
}
```